Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "App\Models\User" not found in subdomain
I have created seperate MVC directories one for the main domain this is domain.com which is working fine and the second for the subdomain that is sub.domain.com but in this getting this error where as it was working fine in xampp
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "App\Models\User" not found in /home/u527983822/domains/domain.com/public_html/momo/app/controllers/home.php:16 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: App\Controllers\Home->index() #1 /home/u527983822/domains/domain.com/public_html/momo/app/core/route/app.php(28): call_user_func_array() #2 /home/u527983822/domains/domain.com/public_html/momo/index.php(9): App\Core\Route\App->__construct() #3 {main} thrown in /home/u527983822/domains/domain.com/public_html/sub/app/controllers/home.php on line 16

look my home.php controllers
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Core\Controller\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Core\Csrf\CSRFHelper;
use App\Models\Lead;
use App\Models\Agent;
use DateTime;

class Home extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $authenticator = new User();
        $agents_activity = new Agent();


here is models
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Core\Database\Database;
use App\Libs\PHPMailer\EmailSender;

class User
{


here is my structure

this is main  domain.com
│   ├── app
│   ├── assets
│   ├── --------------sub/
│   │                 └── -----app     this is  sub.domain.com
│   ├──vendor         ├── ------assets
│   ├── htaccess      ├── ------vendor
│   ├── composer.json ├── ------.htaccess
│   ├── composer.lock ├── ------composer.json
│   ├── index.php     ├── ------composer.lock
                      ├── ------ index.php


At a guess - you have forgotten to include vendor\autoload.php a the top of the index file. Or your composer config is wrong. Also, this type of projects files structure is a terrible idea.

Hi, try running the composer dump-autoload command to update the autoloader
